# Loading Images with Glide and FirebaseUI in newest Firebase Version (10.2.4)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage, android-glide, firebaseui

So I updated firebase to the newest version (10.2.4) alongside playservices, and suddenly all the images in my app loaded with Glide are no longer loading.
If I have this in my build.gradle

```
ext {
    supportLibraryVersion = '25.3.1'
    firebaseLibraryVersion = '10.2.1'
    playServicesLibraryVersion = '10.2.1'
}

dependencies {
    // play services
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:$playServicesLibraryVersion"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:$playServicesLibraryVersion"
    // firebase
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:$firebaseLibraryVersion"
    // ...
}
```

Running this line of Code Works Fine.

```
Glide.with(mContext).using(new FirebaseImageLoader()).load(storageReference).into(viewHolder.profileImage);
```

However, if I set firebase and play services to the newest version:

```
ext {
    supportLibraryVersion = '25.3.1'
    firebaseLibraryVersion = '10.2.4'
    playServicesLibraryVersion = '10.2.4'
}
```

Then the line above doesn't work anymore. It simply doesn't load the Image.
I changed the code to this so I could look at what the error could be:

```
    Glide.with(mContext)
            .using(new FirebaseImageLoader())
            .load(storageReference)
            .listener(new RequestListener<StorageReference, GlideDrawable>() {
        @Override
        public boolean onException(Exception e, StorageReference model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
            Log.d(TAG, "exception " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, StorageReference model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {
            return false;
        }
    }).into(viewHolder.mProfileImage);
```

I get this Log Statement:

```
Could not open resulting stream.
```

and this Exception:

```
  W/System.err: java.io.IOException: Could not open resulting stream.
05-08 19:10:04.513 8839-8839/com.gmail.linxydev.clientapp W/System.err:     at com.google.firebase.storage.StreamDownloadTask.zzacI(Unknown Source)
05-08 19:10:04.513 8839-8839/com.gmail.linxydev.clientapp W/System.err:     at com.google.firebase.storage.StreamDownloadTask.zza(Unknown Source)
05-08 19:10:04.513 8839-8839/com.gmail.linxydev.clientapp W/System.err:     at com.google.firebase.storage.StreamDownloadTask$1.zzacK(Unknown Source)
05-08 19:10:04.513 8839-8839/com.gmail.linxydev.clientapp W/System.err:     at com.google.firebase.storage.StreamDownloadTask$1.call(Unknown Source)
05-08 19:10:04.514 8839-8839/com.gmail.linxydev.clientapp W/System.err:     at com.google.firebase.storage.StreamDownloadTask$zza.zzacM(Unknown Source)
05-08 19:10:04.514 8839-8839/com.gmail.linxydev.clientapp W/System.err:     at com.google.firebase.storage.StreamDownloadTask$zza.read(Unknown Source)
05-08 19:10:04.514 8839-8839/com.gmail.linxydev.clientapp W/System.err:     at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:290)
05-08 19:10:04.514 8839-8839/com.gmail.linxydev.clientapp W/System.err:     at com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.bitmap.RecyclableBufferedInputStream.fillbuf(RecyclableBufferedInputStream.java:166)
05-08 19:10:04.514 8839-8839/com.gmail.linxydev.clientapp W/System.err:     at com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.bitmap.RecyclableBufferedInputStream.read(RecyclableBufferedInputStream.java:229)
05-08 19:10:04.514 8839-8839/com.gmail.linxydev.clientapp W/System.err:     at com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.bitmap.ImageHeaderParser$StreamReader.getUInt16(ImageHeaderParser.java:334)
05-08 19:10:04.514 8839-8839/com.gmail.linxydev.clientapp W/System.err:     at com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.bitmap.ImageHeaderParser.getType(ImageHeaderParser.java:87)
05-08 19:10:04.514 8839-8839/com.gmail.linxydev.clientapp W/System.err:     at com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.gifbitmap.GifBitmapWrapperResourceDecoder$ImageTypeParser.parse(GifBitmapWrapperResourceDecoder.java:147)
05-08 19:10:04.514 8839-8839/com.gmail.linxydev.clientapp W/System.err:     at com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.gifbitmap.GifBitmapWrapperResourceDecoder.decodeStream(GifBitmapWrapperResourceDecoder.java:82)
05-08 19:10:04.514 8839-8839/com.gmail.linxydev.clientapp W/System.err:     at com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.gifbitmap.GifBitmapWrapperResourceDecoder.decode(GifBitmapWrapperResourceDecoder.java:71)
05-08 19:10:04.514 8839-8839/com.gmail.linxydev.clientapp W/System.err:     at com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.gifbitmap.GifBitmapWrapperResourceDecoder.decode(GifBitmapWrapperResourceDecoder.java:61)
05-08 19:10:04.514 8839-8839/com.gmail.linxydev.clientapp W/System.err:     at com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.gifbitmap.GifBitmapWrapperResourceDecoder.decode(GifBitmapWrapperResourceDecoder.java:22)
05-08 19:10:04.514 8839-8839/com.gmail.linxydev.clientapp W/System.err:     at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.decodeFromSourceData(DecodeJob.java:190)
05-08 19:10:04.514 8839-8839/com.gmail.linxydev.clientapp W/System.err:     at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.decodeSource(DecodeJob.java:177)
05-08 19:10:04.514 8839-8839/com.gmail.linxydev.clientapp W/System.err:     at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.decodeFromSource(DecodeJob.java:128)
05-08 19:10:04.514 8839-8839/com.gmail.linxydev.clientapp W/System.err:     at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.EngineRunnable.decodeFromSource(EngineRunnable.java:122)
05-08 19:10:04.514 8839-8839/com.gmail.linxydev.clientapp W/System.err:     at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.EngineRunnable.decode(EngineRunnable.java:101)
05-08 19:10:04.514 8839-8839/com.gmail.linxydev.clientapp W/System.err:     at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.EngineRunnable.run(EngineRunnable.java:58)
05-08 19:10:04.514 8839-8839/com.gmail.linxydev.clientapp W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:423)
05-08 19:10:04.514 8839-8839/com.gmail.linxydev.clientapp W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
05-08 19:10:04.514 8839-8839/com.gmail.linxydev.clientapp W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
05-08 19:10:04.514 8839-8839/com.gmail.linxydev.clientapp W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
05-08 19:10:04.514 8839-8839/com.gmail.linxydev.clientapp W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
05-08 19:10:04.514 8839-8839/com.gmail.linxydev.clientapp W/System.err:     at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.executor.FifoPriorityThreadPoolExecutor$DefaultThreadFactory$1.run(FifoPriorityThreadPoolExecutor.java:118)
```

Going back to version 10.2.1 fixes the problems, however maybe there is another fix? I tested this on 2 devices, one running android 6 and the other running 7, and it happened on both.

Comment: What version of FirebaseUI are you using?

Comment: newest one, its only one class for storage.

Comment: Can you run the code without minifyEnabled so the Exception will be clearer?

Comment: It is not enabled, I believe google obfuscates their firebase libraries.

Comment: Can't comment, so I'll just drop a note here: This error happens only if you use glide 3.8.0: downgrade glide to 3.7.0 and everything works ok!

Comment: I have this exact problem too. And now with the release of 10.2.6 I can't use the new Firebase Perf tools.

Answer (score 0):

For me this seems to be [fixed](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues/730) with the latest 11.0.1 release used in combination with firebase-ui-2.0.1. I don't know what changed though.