# Unable to show image from firebase storage using Glide?

Tags: android, image, firebase, firebase-storage, android-glide

I have taken two approaches to fetch images from firebase storage using glide. The first approach is working fine because after getting downloadUrl it's loading the image using glide.

But the second one is more convenient, but it is not working for me.

buidl.gradle : app

```
  dependencies {
      // ..... not included glige dependency
      compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:0.6.0'
  }
```

First approach (working):

```
// question.imgQuestion  = "qimgs/-KiTpzP5t-xJOO5nSK0A/1493896460324-ch1pg2.jpg"
final StorageReference ref = mStorage.getReference().child(question.imgQuestion);

ref.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
       Log.i(TAG, "Download URL : " + uri); // https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/questionpaper-ce229.appspot.com/o/qimgs%2F-KiTpzP5t-xJOO5nSK0A%2F1493896460324-ch1pg2.jpg?alt=media&token=ca2a3f6e-3eb5-4088-a48d-069ac8ad640b
       Glide.with(QuizActivity.this)
                .load(uri)
                .override(Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL, Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL)
                .into(mImageQuestion);
    }
});
```

Second approach (not working, but I want this)

```
// question.imgQuestion  = "qimgs/-KiTpzP5t-xJOO5nSK0A/1493896460324-ch1pg2.jpg"
final StorageReference ref = mStorage.getReference().child(question.imgQuestion);
Glide.with(QuizActivity.this)
    .using(new FirebaseImageLoader())
    .load(ref)
    .override(Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL, Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL)
    .into(mImageQuestion);
```

Note: This firebase storage instance is an authenticated one.

Comment: Code looks okay.  Is there any error message?  Consider adding a `RequestListener` to get more status.  See this question for example code: http://stackoverflow.com/q/43853592/4815718. You could also try using a more recent version of the FirebaseUI library.  Latest is 1.2.0.

Comment: Thanks, it is due to the library version issue. Used FirebaseUI Version:1.2.0, and Firebase/Play Services Version: 10.2.0.  now it is working.

Answer (score 0):

```
StorageReference imagepath = storageReference.child("Images");   
 imagepath.putFile(selectedImage).addOnSuccessListener(new 
 OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {


                getimage = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();

     Glide.with(QuizActivity.this)
.using(new FirebaseImageLoader())
.load(getimage)
.override(Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL, Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL)
.into(mImageQuestion);
                }
            });
```

Try this, this worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue too, it turned out that the latest version of the firebase SDK (10.2.4) was causing the issue, so I reverted to 10.2.1 and all is well.

Answer (score -1):

Replace `.load(ref)` with `.load(ref.getDownloadUrl())`

```
Glide.with(QuizActivity.this)
.using(new FirebaseImageLoader())
.load(ref.getDownloadUrl())
.override(Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL, Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL)
.into(mImageQuestion);
```

Comment: Statement `.load(ref.getDownloadUrl())` is not allowed by compiler.

Comment: .load method will take firebase storage object in argument.